# How can I install distribute for iPython running on Windows 7?

Tags: python, ipython

I installed iPython on windows 7 without distribute. I read that without distribute, there is no  Python startup menu. And, I cannot figure out how to install distribute.

Is there another way to run iPython? This is really bothering me. I cant seem to open a console!

Comment: See http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#installation-instructions : Download distribute_setup.py and execute it, using the Python interpreter of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me under Windows 7 with Python 3.2.3 and IPython 0.12.1

```
 C:\Python32\Scripts\ipython3.exe
```

You could just create a shortcut for it.

Alternatively, type the above command in from the windows command shell to start up IPython.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/IPython-User-Incomplete-Windows-7-installation-td4380346.html) you need to install "distribute" because it is needed on Windows 7. This link also provides a download.